# When filtering data, how to display only the number of records found?

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js

When the filter is executed, the total number of records is displayed, but it is necessary that only amount found. How can do that?

```
module.exports.getAll = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const users = await Users
            .select()
            .where("LOGIN", "like", `%${req.query.search}%`)
            .orWhere("EMAIL", "like", `%${req.query.search}%`)
            .orderBy(req.query.sort, req.query.order)
            .offset(req.query.pageSize * (req.query.page - 1))
            .limit(req.query.pageSize)
            .exec();
        const rowCount = await Users.count();
        await res.status(200).json({ rowCount: rowCount, users: users });
    } catch (e) {
        errorHandler(res, e);
    }
};
```

JSON example:

```
{
    "rowCount": 100,
    "imp_ad_users": [
        {
            "login": "lodara",
            "email": "lodara@mailnowapp.com"
            "id": 87
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
users.length
```

should do it? or do i missunderstood something?

Comment: It is necessary to display the desired number of records when filtering. Let's say the total number of entries is 100. But when filtering by any value, it approximately finds only 2 records. But my record count is always 100 s and without filtering.

Comment: so user. length should do it? you get the users by querying in an array.

Comment: It will always display count 100

Comment: how many objects you get when you print the users ?
console.log(users)
console.log(users.length)

Comment: It gives me nothing but `undefined`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

please copy paste inside project, it has to work.

```
module.exports.getAll = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const users = await Users
            .select()
            .where("LOGIN", "like", `%${req.query.search}%`)
            .orWhere("EMAIL", "like", `%${req.query.search}%`)
            .orderBy(req.query.sort, req.query.order)
            .offset(req.query.pageSize * (req.query.page - 1))
            .limit(req.query.pageSize)
            .exec();
        await res.status(200).json({ rowCount: users.length, users: users });
    } catch (e) {
        errorHandler(res, e);
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't have `length` in the model displays `undefined`, here's how I display the number of entries `const rowCount = await Users.count();`. But this does not work correctly when filtering.

Comment: IMO with const rowCount = await Users.count(); you count every user in DB. user.length should give back the length of the userarray? Did you test my code? it has nothing todo with the property of the model.

Comment: Tested always produces `undefined`